# Identifying duplicate rows in MDX UNION

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I have a report where I need to account for some rows in a set against more than one grouping.

This is a finance report and for particular posting codes, I need to include their actual and budget values in another grouping within the dimension hierarchy.

To do this I thought to use a UNION with the ALL option to bring in ALLMEMBERS and duplicate the specific posting code(s). This works in generating my dataset where I can see the duplicate rows.

Now I need to be able to identify the duplicate rows in order to create a MEMBER value that will be used to group the duplicates against a different heading code. My experimentation to date hasn't helped find the magic bullet to identify the duplicates.

A MDX snippet with my union:

```
union 
  ( 
     [Statement Financial Analysis].[Report Framework].[Post Code Key].ALLMEMBERS
   , [Statement Financial Analysis].[Report Framework].[Post Code Key].&[xxxx]
     , all
  )
```

Any ideas or tips on different methods to achieve this end?

Comment: Is there any example of dataset? I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like this to extract counts:

```
COUNT(
  EXISTS(
    EXISTING [Statement Financial Analysis].[Report Framework].[Post Code Key].MEMBERS
    ,
    ,'<Measure Group Name here>'
  )
)
```

This should help identify duplicates.

But if you need to specify a specific member then maybe intersect:

```
COUNT(
  INTERSECT(
    EXISTING [Statement Financial Analysis].[Report Framework].[Post Code Key].MEMBERS
    ,[Statement Financial Analysis].[Report Framework].[Post Code Key].&[xxxx]
    ,ALL
  )
)
```

Comment: I don't have any data I can share. If it helps clarify, what I would do if I were reporting from SQL is something like: select group_code, posting_code, actuals, budget from GL union all select "ZZZ" as group_code, "YYY" as posting_code, actuals, budget from GL where posting_code = "XXX". I would then have posting code "XXX" actuals and budget selected twice, but with different group and posting codes for the second iteration.